# Python type annotations Simpy package with Mypy

Tags: python, mypy, simpy

I’m adding type annotations to my Simpy simulation. I run into trouble assigning a type annotation to some of the functions, as I do not know whether I should use `Generator`, `Iterable` or `Iterator`. As a minimum example, I tried adding annotations to an example of the Simpy docs (see: https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/process_interaction.html):

```
from random import seed, randint
seed(23)

import simpy

class EV:
     def __init__(self, env):
         self.env = env
         self.drive_proc = env.process(self.drive(env))
         self.bat_ctrl_proc = env.process(self.bat_ctrl(env))
         self.bat_ctrl_reactivate = env.event()

     def drive(self, env):
         while True:
             # Drive for 20-40 min
             yield env.timeout(randint(20, 40))

             # Park for 1–6 hours
             print('Start parking at', env.now)
             self.bat_ctrl_reactivate.succeed()  # "reactivate"
             self.bat_ctrl_reactivate = env.event()
             yield env.timeout(randint(60, 360))
             print('Stop parking at', env.now)

     def bat_ctrl(self, env):
         while True:
             print('Bat. ctrl. passivating at', env.now)
             yield self.bat_ctrl_reactivate  # "passivate"
             print('Bat. ctrl. reactivated at', env.now)

             # Intelligent charging behavior here …
             yield env.timeout(randint(30, 90))

env = simpy.Environment()
ev = EV(env)
env.run(until=150)
```

If I now want to add type annotation to the function `drive()` then any combination of the `Generator` type passes mypy’s tests (for Example `Generator[None, None, None], Generator[int, float, None], Generator[int, None, None])`, but also type annotations of `Iterable` and `Iterator` are fine. How can I determine the correct type annotation in this case (but also in general)?

I tried finding the answer in the Simpy documentation, but I did not find information on which type annotation I should use. I read the Mypy documentation about Generators but that did not help me further.

Answer (score 1):

In python **Iterable** is an object, that one can iterate over. It generates an Iterator when passed to iter() method. An iterator is an object, which is used to iterate over an iterable object using the `__next__` method. Iterators have the `__next__` method, which returns the next item of the object. Every iterator is also an iterable, but not every iterable is an iterator. As well as every generator is an iterator, but not vice versa.
That's why sometimes, you can annotate same function with Generator, Iterator and Iterable and it will pass mypy's tests.
If you would like to decide which one is better suits your code read official Typing docs.